# Record and play audio on silent mode just do it once

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am recording audio in a view controller and displaying a button for the user to play it on a second view controller.

The thing is that I am using this code on the second view so the audio can be played even on silent mode:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                         sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
```

But when I go back to record a second audio, it does not play on the second screen.

Any leads on this? Seems like I have to change those settings again to its originals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
                             sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
```

Some time ago I had the similar issue, but I was using AVAudioSession. The problem was the same, then I found one thing, it may be usefull for you:

record was working fine, then after I playback something it stop working at all. The problem was I resetedup AVAudioSession to playback category by calling

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

after that recording stop working. There is a two ways to fix it, setup audio session defire recording to `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` and before playback to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` or setup with `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.

after I did

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

everything started to work fine.